# Version control problem

Tags: version-control, git, svn

I heavily use Excel and CSV at my workplace.

**File 0 Excel File**

The initial file is an Excel file. Let's call this File 0. This may or may not change with time depending upon the requirement of the project and input of the client.

**File 1 CSV Data Sheet**

By observing the notes in File 0, a CSV file is created. Let's call this File 1. This is a data sheet, and changes are made in it from time to time. The change in data sometimes comes over email or has to be pooled in from a database that outputs CSV files. These new files are joined to File 1 as a part of changes in File 1.

**File 2 Excel File**

Based on notes in File 0 and variable names in File 1, multiple instances of File 2 are created, and each instance is changed from time to time with changes in File 1 and client input and requirements.

**File 3 Excel File**

For multiple instances and changes in every instance, one File 3 every time.

Now, I want to keep a track of all the changes made into these files along with the files.

All the changes are important as at any point in time the client can go back to some old version of any of the above mentioned files. Please provide a naming convention and also a way to keep the change log efficiently.

There are multiple people working on the same project. Also, the Excel files have multiple sheets.

**Note:**

1. I cannot use any external software like SVN, git, or any other paid or free software.
2. If any part is unclear, comment, and I'll explain it.

Comment: "*Cannot use any external softwares like SVN, git or any other paid or free software.* -- **Why??**

Comment: You're essentially saying:  "I have a simple problem that has been solved many times before.  I won't tell you why we can't use a standard solution, and I'm suggesting a really bad starting point for a custom solution.  Do your best."  Like Keith has asked: Why are you limiting yourself this way??

Comment: @Keith: As it is a company PC no installation permissions are provided. The administrator rights remain with the offshore team. They won't allow us anything of this sort. So all we have at our disposal is Word, excel, notepad and endless folders and naming riights to aolve this issue.

Comment: @Metafight: Had this been solved by me ever, I wouldn't have taken the pain of writing such a long question.

Comment: It's a great pity that you aren't allowed to use the tools you need to do your job. You're describing a problem that can be solved by using source control software. *Somebody* has the ability and permission to install software on the computer you're using. Ask them to do it rather than wasting time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as abrupt or rude, but trying to implement your own version control from scratch is a bad idea.  The kind of bad idea that will end up costing you a lot of time and money.  It's probably a better idea (more cost effective) to get permission to install git on there.

Comment: I guess there is VCS software which does not need administrative rights for the installation. May this an option for you?

Comment: This question makes feel so sad. But if your problem doesn't required edits in parallel revisions to be merged, you could then keep a linear history, e.g. the _v4, _v5 method. Exporting to a csv format and writing a delta engine is not too hard, it's tracking the integration history between branches and doing merges of widely diverged files. In Excel, I think there are ambiguous merges due to column row. Good luck, you'll need it.

Comment: I am actually not sure a VCS is the solution to your problem. How many people are involved in the process? Are they working in different places, where the documents are exchanged by email? Do they need a changelog summary at hand when they open the specific version of the excel sheet? Indenpendently from using a VCS or not, it is probably a good idea to reserve a  worksheet inside the Excel document for the changelog summary, with columns "date of change", "author", "content of change".

Comment: @DocBrown: 3 to 4 people are involved in the process. All of them work together and no files are exchanged over emails. Yes changelog summary is required as say the person working with the Instance 1 of File 2 is on leave and that instance needs to be handled by someone else. He/she needs to know what are the last implemented changes in instance 1.

Comment: For this situation, introducing a VCS is surely a good idea. However, as I said, writing a separate changelog summary will still make a lot of sense. In Excel. including that in the file itself is perfectly possible, easy, and avoids the changelog to be separated from the document version where it belongs to. However, people will need a little bit of self discipline, there is no way around this.

Comment: Is there some naming convention, multiple folder/subfolder system coupled with text files, word documents and excel files for the system.

Comment: There is no "standard convention", you need to tailor this to your situation by yourself and try it out with your colleagues. Using a VCS may allow you to keep the basic structure of your working directories clean and simple, because you do not have to abuse it for keeping the history. Moreover, it may be a good idea to inform yourself about the different options for comparing Excel sheets semi-automatically, Google ist your friend. Which one works best for you however is very dependent from the structure of your documents.

Comment: Any reason you can't use Excel change tracking itself? CSVs can be transformed to/from Excel, so potentially you could use the Excel change tracking in combination with some kind of linear naming convention (_v2, _v3) as suggested.

Comment: There are literally dozens of solutions to this problem out there. Many of them allow you to version both the data and any VBA that exists in the project. The cost of rolling your own will far exceed the cost of purchasing a tool. Do your due diligence and calculate the cost it would take to maintain this half assed system that you're creating vs. the cost of the off the shelf software. Put it into a language mgmt can understand, $$$. If they can't understand that it will cost far less to purchase something, you don't want to be working there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at portable git?  Just a thought...

I haven't used this myself but here's what https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitportable/ says;

- Runs a complete Git instance.
- Completely portable - runs off a USB or hard drive.
- ***Does not require administrator privileges.***
- No need for any external software - simply download extract and run!
- Packaged in PortableApps.com format for easy integration.

(emphasis mine)

See also https://superuser.com/questions/190056/git-vs-portable-git, and  https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: This feels to be the end of the problem. But will it keep a track of changes made to excel files without me typing down every single change made into a change log?

Comment: What I was looking for is series of folders and text files with naming convention based on dates and versions and manual changelog for the entire system.

Comment: Ah, my bad; I must have I misunderstood. Git will track changes thru revisions identified by branches or tags etc.. and it can do diffs between them but you may not like the result if you're looking for some specific notion of changes in Excel files.  As others mentioned, Git provides branches and tags that might possibly used to handle at least part of the date and version naming conventions as well as branch or lineage change log.

Comment: While git won't make the folders appear all at once, it will give you the ability to travel through the history of your git repository, so that you'll be able to view the application, as it was, on a certain date.

Comment: Git isn't a viable solution for versioning the data in an excel workbook. Not unless you go through the trouble of unzipping the file into its raw XML before each and every checkin.